# Can I adjust automatically lighting / colour leveling for all frames?

Tags: rendering, image, lighting, grease-pencil, compositing-nodes

I would like to know how to adjust lighting and colour to match each frame level and do not know if this is possible in blender or if I will have to learn and use something like Open-ColourIO.

If I have images as planes projected onto geometry such as mountains or buildings, the images colour levels will very likely all be different, from different cameras etc.

So, how can I balance footage with many frames, and images, to a balanced averaged level for contrast, colour etc, as well as have the image from grease pencil and the 3d scene/objects, have similar levels?

### Is this possible, or do I have to do this in another way, and how would you do it if it is not possible, thanks.

The answer given below is probably correct, but it is too complicated for me to understand or probably do.  I assume this task is too difficult at present for an "average low level blender user" to understand, and will probably just do what I can unless another post appears. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a great question, and the "best answer" is a little more complicated than you probably want, as well as depends on your sources of footage.

You are projecting emissions, represented by your RGB code values. This means a few useful things:

1. Your RGB lights must be aligned to whatever colour space you are using. Typically around these parts that means your RGB lights must be BT.709 with a D65 colour when R=G=B. That's basically scene linear sRGB in other terms.
2. If you have the source camera encodes, you can convert the "raw" camera encode to a linear 16 bit TIFF with BT.709 lights. This is ideal.
3. If you don't have the source camera encodes, it's a bit sloppy. You could do a little OCIO magic and make a transform that treats the aesthetic contrast JPEG or whatever as Filmic + Look, and inverts it as best as it can. That will be wrong, but less wrong than using the sRGB transfer function.
4. If you are using footage, it's going to be either a log encoded footage properly transformed to BT.709 scene linear, or the second hackish case.

Once everything is in the scene referred domain, it is simply a matter of balancing your emissions to a ground truth. This is tricky, but not nearly as tricky as trying to do it without considering 1-4 above.

Hope this helps. If you have more information, post it, and I'll do my best to help you along further if I can.